# Вывод двух одинаковых названий столбцов

Tags: php, yii

таблица1 table1 - поле name

таблица 2 table2 - поле name

Как вывести значение name двух одинаковых названий столбцов из БД mysql?

Контроллер:

```
$advert = Advert::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT table1.name, table2.name
FROM table1, table2');
$this->render('index', array('model' => $advert));
```

вид:

```
<?php foreach ($model as  $advert){?>
//пробовал так не помогает 
<?php echo $advert->table1.name ?> 
<?php echo $advert->table2.name ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы же понимаете, что не бывает в массиве 2-х одинаковых ключей с разными значениями, точно так же как и двух одинаковых свойств с разными значениями.

```
SELECT table1.name AS name_table_1, table2.name AS name_table_2 FROM table1, table2

<?php echo $advert->name_table_1 ?> 
<?php echo $advert->name_table_2 ?>
```

И почитайте чёнить про нормализацию баз данных и про объекты в PHP почитайте, раз вы позволили себе написать имя свойства содержащую точку

Comment: Дело в том что я так и делал но ошибка

Не определено свойство "Advert. name_table_1".

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$advert = Advert::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT table1.name AS t1_name, table2.name
FROM table1 AS t2_name, table2.*');
$this->render('index', array('model' => $advert));

<?php foreach ($model as  $advert){?>
<?php echo $advert->t1_name ?> 
<?php echo $advert->t2_name ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов несколько, самый простой конечно тот, который вы собираетесь использовать. Ничего сложного в нем нет, нужно просто одной из столбцов назначит алиас

```
$advert = Advert::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT table1.name AS t1_name, table2.name AS t2_name
FROM table1, table2');
```

**t1_name** и **t2_name** имена алиасов, которые я придумал, могут быть совершенно любыми.

Но в будущем смотрите в сторону конструктора запросов. Кстати у вас нет связки в запросе. Т.е. логически таблица 2 не ссылается на таблицу 1 как на критерии. И возможно когда Вы попытаетесь выполнить запрос, то будет ошибка.